# output sql table to HTML using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need my php to print out an HTML table of all the weather reports and the name and email of the person. 
it gives me an error
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in

Here is my code

```
$query = "SELECT weather.report,
 cities.name, cities.email FROM weather INNER JOIN cities ON weather.city=cities.city ";


$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    //$stmt->bind_param("s", $player); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($tempCity, $tempReport, $tempName, $tempEmail); 
    echo "<table width=500 border=1 cellpadding=5>
            <tr><th>Temperature</th><th>Report</th><th>City</th><th>DATE</th></tr>";

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$tempCity."</td>
                <td>".$tempReport."</td>
                <td>".$tempName."</td>
        <td>".$tempEmail."</td>
              </tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    $error = "Sorry could not retrieve information";  echo $error;  return;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

thank you for any help

Comment: Literally what it says lol, You need to bind selected items in your query. So report, name, email.  You can only have 3 in the bind_result if you only bind three, you know?

Comment: if you select *3* items (report, name, email) you can't bind 4 results : $tempCity, $tempReport, $tempName, $tempEmail (EDIT: note to myself: refresh page before giving same answer as above ^^)

Comment: @OldPadawan I totally meant to delete that comment after adding the answer haha

Comment: @clearshot66 : I'm not the only one in "cap'tain obvious mode" -> check below ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what it says, literally. You need to bind the exact amount of selected items in your query. So report, name, email from your "SELECT .....  You can only have 3 in the bind_result if you only select three, you know?  So

```
$stmt->bind_result($tempCity, $tempReport, $tempName, $tempEmail);
```

Should be

```
  $stmt->bind_result($tempReport, $tempName, $tempEmail);
```

Binds also must be in the order in which you select them. If you flipped report and city, the report data would go into city and vice versa when binding. Just a note

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned three fields in select statement and pass four parameters in bind_result function. So bind_result couldnt find 4th parameter in select

Remove one parameter from function call
$stmt->bind_result($tempReport, $tempName, $tempEmail);

Or

Add city in select statement